# If the function is increasing for all real values of x , what is the range of a?

Tags: calculus

Let $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}|\log_{2}(\log_3(\log_4(\cos t +a)))|\ dt$$be increasing for all real values of $x$, then $a$ belongs to ?

Where $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value function.

---

I have thought of the solution this way 
In the given function , if we apply Leibniz's rule for differentiation under the integral sign

We get

$f'(x)=\log_{2}(\log_3(\log_4(cosx +a)) ...... (1)$

Since in the question , it is given that the function is increasing , then we can use the relation that 
$f'(x)\geq0$

Now from equation (1)

$\log_{2}(\log_3(\log_4(cosx +a)) \geq0$

$\log_3(\log_4(cosx +a) \geq1$

$\log_4(cosx +a) \geq3$

$cos x +a \geq64$

But I'm stuck here , what value of $\cos x$ should I consider ? Maximum value ? If not , what ?

Even if we consider the maximum value , the range of $a$ doesn't match the answer given , which is $a \in [5,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, if $a$ is very big and positive then the integrand will be positive, and so its integral $f$ will be increasing.

But how big does $a$ need to be? Is $a>2018$ enough, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Since integrand has absolute value only issue is arguments to log functions being positive (possibly zero at isolated points with corresponding convergence analysis).

But as concrete answer to your question, the minimum value of cos function. If min value satisfies inequality then all values will. If inequality was less than it would have been maximum value.

So, as you did but instead of 0,1,3,64 in right hand side it would be N/A, 0, 1, 4. And 4+1=5.

Comment: Could you rather explain your last line , more specifically the part "instead of 0,1,3,64 in right hand side it would be N/A, 0, 1, 4" , how come ?